# grpc epoll fd: 4 error in cloud ml job

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I am trying to run a job in cloud ML. This is the first one so I am not doing anything fancy (or I am not aware of it). I  have tried the the job locally and it worked fine. I am submitting the job like this:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME --job-dir $OUTPUT --module-name trainer.task --package-path trainer/ --runtime-version 1.2 -- --train-files $TRAIN_DATA --eval-files $EVAL_DATA --verbosity DEBUG
```

I hava a setup.py file as I need tf 1.4.

I am getting the following error in the cloud ml job:

```
17:37:18.590 master-replica-0 grpc epoll fd: 4
{
 insertId:  "3bz8czg6uycja0"   
 jsonPayload: {
  created:  1511887038.59055    
  levelname:  "ERROR"    
  lineno:  1051    
  message:  "    grpc epoll fd: 4"    
  pathname:  "ev_epoll1_linux.c"    
  thread:  228    
 }
 labels: {
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_id:  "56570433820965707"    
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_name:  "cmle-training-master-93c1f629dc-0-1sbpv"    
  compute.googleapis.com/zone:  "europe-west1-c"    
  ml.googleapis.com/job_id:  "XXXXX"    
  ml.googleapis.com/job_id/log_area:  "root"    
  ml.googleapis.com/task_name:  "master-replica-0"    
  ml.googleapis.com/trial_id:  ""    
 }
 logName:  "projects/fibi-tech/logs/master-replica-0"   
 receiveTimestamp:  "2017-11-28T16:37:27.139888642Z"   
 resource: {
  labels: {…}   
  type:  "ml_job"    
 }
 severity:  "ERROR"   
 timestamp:  "2017-11-28T16:37:18.590551137Z"   
}
```

After the error nothing else happens (at least not for up to ten minutes) and I have to stop de job manually.

Thank you!

Comment: Similar here, but getting error message `grpc epoll fd: 3`

Comment: Well, this tag is supposed to be reviewed by cloud-ml engineers, but looks like it is not. I guess this is again another google cloud service that looks great on paper, but is a black box an is impossible to find out what is the problem if you have an issue. Been there already, I guess I never learn...

Comment: I asked this same question on https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/m/#!topic/discuss/8lcn7n4IzOQ and one of the engineers asked me to post the question here, but with the tag `google-cloud-ml-engine`. Try adding that tag to your question.

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira I saw the tag you mention on the ml engine documentation, but for some reason stack overflow didn't allow me to use it. Any way, reviewing your answer and related posts I have managed to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue using Estimator API with ml-engine. Solution was to use `tf.estimator.train_and_eval()`. See my other post [ml-engine vague error: "grpc epoll fd: 3"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875972/ml-engine-vague-error-grpc-epoll-fd-3/47899178#47899178)