# ml-engine vague error: "grpc epoll fd: 3"

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, grpc, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to train with `gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training`, and job is getting stuck with the following output on logs:

[image]
[image]

My config.yaml:

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: standard_gpu
  workerType: standard_gpu
  parameterServerType: large_model
  workerCount: 1
  parameterServerCount: 1
```

Any hints about what "grpc epoll fd: 3" means and how to fix that? My input function is feeding a 16G TFRecord from gs://, but with batch = 4, shuffle buffer_size = 4. Each input sample is a single channel 99 x 161px image: shape (15939,) - not huge.

Thanks

Comment: That log line is informational, and it is getting incorrectly flagged as an error.

Comment: Couple of questions: Which version of TensorFlow were you using? Did you install custom TensorFlow? Did you use tf.estiamtors? If yes, did you call train or train_and eval?

Comment: That is running tf 1.4.1 on Google cloud. Here's a related conversation about this with sample code https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/m/#!topic/discuss/8lcn7n4IzOQ

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a bug in the Estimator implementation, not sure. The solution for now is to use `tf.estimator.train_and_eval` as suggested by @guoqing-xu

#### Working sample

```
train_input_fn = gen_input(FLAGS.train_input)
eval_input_fn = gen_input(FLAGS.eval_input)

model_params = {
  'learning_rate': FLAGS.learning_rate,
}

estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_dir=model_dir, model_fn=model_fn, params=model_params)
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=1000)
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=eval_input_fn, steps=None, start_delay_secs=30, throttle_secs=30)

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the summary! We will create documentation to explain when to use what.

Comment: It looks quite a bit hacky. Any updates on how to properly fix this?